# Apache multiple local virtual host

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm working on an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Apache and I'm trying to setup 2 virtual host.  The problem is I don't know how to setup the .conf files correctly so that I can hit both virtual host correctly from a remote machine...

For example if the Ubuntu sever has an address of 192.168.1.3, and I'm using another machine, how can I access each virtual host with `http://192.168.1.3/host1` and `http://192.168.1.3/host2`?

right now in my /etc/apache2/sites-available folder I have the following 2 files

**host1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 192.168.1.3/host1
ServerAlias host1
DocumentRoot /var/www/host1/
.....
```

**host2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 192.168.1.3/host2
ServerAlias host2
DocumentRoot /var/www/host2/
.....
```

what is the correct configuration to make the virtual host work correctly when accessing from a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to assign host names to both your virtual hosts. E.g: host1.local.com & host2.local.com. Then in your remote machine, open /etc/hosts (you will require sudo privileges) and add the following lines:

```
192.168.1.3 host1.local.com
192.168.1.3 host2.local.com
```

Your virtual hosts config would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName host1.local.com
```